# How can QML native `date` type be updated?

Tags: qt, qml, qdate

QML provides a [`date` type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-date.html) that appears to be freely convertible to and from both the [C++ `QDate` class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html) and the [QML `Date` type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-date.html). The `Date` type is an extension of the [JS `Date` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Calling the `set` methods on a `date` property is apparently permissible, because no error (e.g. "method missing") is thrown:

```
// in a QML object declaration
property date myDate: new Date()
// in a slot somewhere in the object
date.setYear(2002)
```

However, the date data *is not changed*; printing the date before and after calling `setYear` (or any other `set` method) causes exact same date string to be printed twice.

The QML documentation doesn't seem to say much about `date` type in the link provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears (and air-dex's answer seems to confirm) that the `date` type simply can't be directly modified in this way. This is *bizarre*, because there are *no errors* triggered by attempts to call the methods.

So the solution is to simply declare date-objects that must be modified later as `var` rather than `date`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain to you what is wrong with the commented following exemple:

class.hpp

```
#ifndef CLASS_HPP
#define CLASS_HPP

#include <QObject>
#include <QDateTime>

class DateCpp : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        DateCpp();

    protected:
        // QML dates are QDateTime in C++, not QDate.
        Q_PROPERTY(QDateTime fooDate
                   READ getDate
                   WRITE setDate
                   NOTIFY fooDateChanged)
        QDateTime date;
        QDateTime getDate() const;
        void setDate(const QDateTime & d);

    signals:
        void dateChanged();
};

#endif
```

class.cpp

```
#include "class.hpp"

DateCpp::DateCpp() : QObject(), date() {}

QDateTime DateCpp::getDate() const
{
    return this->date;
}

void DateCpp::setDate(const QDateTime & newDate)
{
    this->date = newDate;

    /*
     * You have to tell QML that the property value has changed.
     * For this, use the NOTIFY signal of the property. If you do not emit it,
     * the property will not by updated on the QML side.
     */
    emit fooDateChanged();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQml>
#include "class.hpp"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Do not forget to declare your object to QML. ;-)
    qmlRegisterType<DateCpp>("Foobar", 3, 14, "DateQML");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return a.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import Foobar 3.14

Rectangle {
    id: rect

    // A QML date (treated as a QDateTime by the engine).
    property date rectDate

    /*
     * Binded to myDate.fooDate, but variables are at different memory spaces.
     * Will be changed together nontheless.
     */
    property date rd2: myDate.fooDate

    /*
     * Just like rd2 but it is the same object in memory, a kind of pointer
     * on DateCpp::date.
     */
    property alias rd3: myDate.fooDate

    // No "=" but ":" for property declarations.
    property date aDateProp: Date.now()

    DateQML {
        id: myDate

        // It is a kind of slot connected to the fooDate Q_PROPERTY's NOTIFY signal.
        onFooDateChanged: {
            console.log("The foodate is: " + myDate.fooDate);

            // Will trigger a signal and "onRectDateChanged" will be executed.
            rect.rectDate = myDate.fooDate;
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            /*
             * It is JavaScript. "date d" is consequently wrong here.
             * d will be a QML date (treated as a QDateTime by the engine).
             */
            var d = Date.now();
            d.setYear(2002);

            // Calls the fooDate Q_PROPERTY's WRITE method, i.e. DateCpp::setDate();.
            myDate.fooDate = d;

            /*
             * If DateCpp::setDate(); is not called here, you can still copy 
             * the property to modify what you want:
             *
             * var d2 = myDate.fooDate;
             * d2.setYear(2025);
             * myDate.fooDate = d2;
             */
            myDate.fooDate.setYear(2025);
        }
    }

    onRectDateChanged: {
        console.log("The QML property has changed: " + rect.rectDate);
    }
}
```

**TL;DR:**

- You are dealing with `QDateTime`s.
- Use the NOTIFY signal to tell the system that the value has changed.
- No `date d` to declare dates in JavaScript.
- There are not any "`=`" in QML properties declaration but "`:`".

Comment: Thanks for giving a complete buildable/runnable example. For your first TL;DR point, are you saying that the QML documentation is wrong? It states, "When integrating with C++, note that any QDate value passed into QML from C++ is automatically converted into a date value, and vice-versa." There is no mention of `QDateTime` on the page. For the third TL;DR point, I realize I didn't correctly indicate the contexts for my two lines of code; I've fixed it to indicate that the `date` declaration is actually a QML property declaration, while the `setYear` call is inside a JS context.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html says:

"*The QML engine provides automatic type conversion between QDateTime values and JavaScript Date objects.*"

My bad. QML basic type `date` is `QDate`. It has nothing to do with JS dates. However there are implicit conversions with QML `Date`s. Those dates are JS dates, so they are `QDateTime`s.

Personally I always work with `QDateTime` properties on the C++ side and `date` properties on the QML side, and I have never had issues about it as far as I remember.

Comment: There is a mistake in your edit. Your date myDate was a QML property, but you cannot use "`=`" in QML properties but "`:`". See my edit. ;-)

Comment: Bleargh, you're right, I should have just copied-and-pasted directly from my actual project code.

Comment: So, it looks like you only actually call the `setDate` method on a `var` declared inside a JS context. Similarly, I noticed that I could get my app to work by declaring the property as a `var` instead of a `date`. So is there no way to directly modify a `date` object without simply overwriting it using `=`?